# How can i get data latlng that i saved in firebase when it trigger by marker android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 data inside firebase which is Latitude Longitude.

Example :

`Data 
     qwe0912830qwiejkasd
          Latitude  : 12345
          Longitude : 23412
     qweoksldfmkl2091kmw
          Latitude  : 23423
          Longitude : 09801`

I have 2 markers on maps and markers location based from data in firebase, what i need is, when i click 1 of 2 markers it shows latitude and longitude written in Toast.

This is what i did, but it crash when i click marker.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                tujuan.setText(marker.getTitle());
                LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
                //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, markerLocation+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pariwisata").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                double latt = (double) snapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                                double longg = (double) snapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,latt+", "+longg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });

                return false;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Data").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        double latt = (double) snapshot.child("latitude").getValue();
        double longg = (double) snapshot.child("longitude").getValue();

     }
}
```

Comment: where do i put this? `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener`?

Comment: I try to put that code inside `mMap. setOnMarkerClickListner`, when i click that marker it stop working

Comment: `Process: stmikbumigoramataram.intro, PID: 3291
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at stmikbumigoramataram.intro.MapsActivity$3$1.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:181)`

Comment: do you have them as strings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168287/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-husen).

Comment: it shows last latitude longitude in firebase, i try to click another marker with different Latitude and longitude but it shows last latitude and longitude in firebase

Comment: red underline on latt, it says `wrong 2nd argument. Found: "double", required:"java.lang.String"`